# Returning the last index of a value in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble with this problem that is asking me to return the last index of a value in an array. This is my code so far, I just need help knowing what to return

```
public int lastIndexOf(int[] nums, int value) {
    for (int i : nums) {
        if (i == value) {
            return;
        } else  {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a normal `for` loop to cycle from the *last* element backwards. An enhanced loop is not a good fit for this problem.

Comment: You don't want to put the `return -1` inside the loop, since then it will terminate as soon as it finds any element not equal to `value`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will never work; it will return the result after visiting the first element of your array instead of visiting each element.

I would suggest you to do that:

```
public int lastIndexOf(int[] nums, int value) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
        if (nums[i] == value)
            index = i;

    return index;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: @nylanderDev please don't drastically change others' answers by adding code that the original poster didn't include. Please post your own answer.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I presumed improvements were acceptable. Thank you for amending the edit.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Maybe I can add his solution to mine then display his name to be fair. Is it good for you @nylanderDev?

Comment: @nylanderDev they are acceptable, but not when they are *that* substantial.

Comment: @0009laH The equivalent solution is now available in Frederico's answer, so I don't think that will benecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to traverse the array backwards, so you can return as soon as you find the right-most element you're looking for.

```
public int lastIndexOf(int[] nums, int value) {
    for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (nums[i] == value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    // the loop ended and we didn't find anything
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I believe there's a typo in your loop condition.

Answer (score 2):

**An alternative using stream(), Collections.reverse() and indexOf()**

```
public int lastIndexOf(int[] nums, int value) {
    List<Integer> numsList = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.reverse(numsList); // now the list is reversed
    return numsList.indexOf(value) == -1 ? -1 : numsList.size() - numsList.indexOf(value) - 1;
}
```